# How to get the 1st occurrence of Sex (male & female both) from sashelp.class

Tags: sql, sas, limit

I am trying to get all the details in a row for the first occurence of sex='m' and sex='f' from sashelp.class.

Sex is a column in sashelp.class

Till now I have done this:

```
Proc sql;
Select *
From sashelp.class
Where sex='m' or sex='f'
Order by sex
Limit 1;
Quit;
```

This gives me an error in the limit statement. Saying "Syntax Error, expecting on of the following: !, !! ... etc"

Comment: So your desired result here is a data set with 2 observations, correct? One that is the first row with Sex = 'M' and one that is the first row with Sex = 'F'.

Comment: @PeterClemmensen Assuming there are rows for both sexes, `order by sex` implies `Sex='f'` would be the *first* row because `f` orders earlier than `m`.

Comment: @PeterClemmensen - yes!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an easy to follow data step approach.

```
data want;
   set sashelp.class;
   if sex = 'M' and m = . then do;
      output; m = 1; 
   end;
   if sex = 'F' and f = . then do;
      output; f = 1; 
   end;
   retain m f;
   drop m f;
run;
```